# Is IP geolocation threat intelligence?

Tags: terminology, geolocation

If the suppliers of your business are all located in North America, but your supplier web portal suddenly receives a lot of traffic from elsewhere, you should investigate. Therefore, IP geolocation data sounds like threat intelligence to me. However, the term *threat intelligence* usually refers to file hashes of malware, IP adresses of command&control servers, etc. but not to geolocation data for IP addresses. What do I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Threat Intelligence" has to have "threat" as a context. A piece of data is just that: data.

The [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyber_threat_intelligence#cite_note-1) links to the CERT-UK's [paper on the subject](https://www.ncsc.gov.uk/guidance/introduction-threat-intelligence) and defines threat intelligence as:

> [It is] evidence-based knowledge, including context, mechanisms,
>   indicators, implications and actionable advice, about an existing or
>   emerging menace or hazard to assets that can be used to inform
>   decisions regarding the subject's response to that menace or hazard.

[quoted from: https://www.gartner.com/doc/2487216/definition-threat-intelligence]

So, just having the geo-location info is the same as having the IP: it's a piece of data. There is no particular relevance to the data, so it is not "threat intelligence". If it was known that major attacks were happening from a particular location (as has happened with Chinese Army attacks coming from known military locations and the IP geo-location data pointed there directly) then *that* context makes this particular piece of data "threat intel".

Just because the geo-ip data is odd for you in this instance does not make the area of knowledge called "geo-location" threat intel. But I'm not sure why one would require that the data be classified this way.

Comment: There's some context bound to the question. It is known that only little of legitimate traffic towards the service should normally originate from anywhere except North America. One can treat *a lot* of traffic coming from elsewhere to be a sign (or, as McMillan puts it, "evidence-based knowledge, including context and indicators, about an emerging menace") of a DDoS threat if they want to. The meaning is vague, the context and the purpose are important.

Comment: On the other hand, *"major attacks were happening from a particular location (as has happened with Chinese Army attacks coming from known military locations)"* – "TI is not simply a list of atomic indicators that 
an attacker used at one point in time", to quote SANS on this.

Comment: @ximaera my comment about major attacks included a current time element (you excluded that from your quotation) meaning that it is not atomic. "Right now, confirmed attacks happening to others from location X." Perfectly fine TI.

Comment: @ximaera even if you want to say that IPs from outside a normal range is classified as "bad" (however you want to define 'normal', 'range' or 'bad'), geo-location data is not TI. It with context might be TI to another party ("we are seeing suspicious traffic to our service from these IPs/locations), but to the first party, it's just data.

Comment: Fine. It might be reasonable to describe here what SIEM is and how it works, because I believe it fully answers the author's question. Let's see if I'll have enough time for that.

Comment: @ximaera ah, I think I see where you are going. I am of the impression that context that you provide for yourself is not TI. Only context from 3rd parties is TI. What you generate for yourself is just data or evidence.

Comment: SANS explicitly mentions "internal threat intelligence" in [its 2016 whitepaper](https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/analyst/threat-intelligence-is-effectively-37282), constituted by "data points and information that are garnered from within the organization itself". But, frankly, I don't think this sort of a terminology is really worth arguing at all.

Comment: Awesome discussion! The threat intelligence provider of my employer provides a feed with ranges of IP addresses, that ISPs assign dynamically. So this data is not real threat intelligence because by itself the data does not indicate a threat. Only with further context, the dyn-IP data and IP geolocation data become useful indicators. Is my reasoning right?